# How to publish R code and graphs (Markdown) on websites?

Tags: r, r-markdown, publish

I would like to setup a homepage and publish several R code mixed with text, pictures and references. Obviously that's what a lot of people do:

https://feliperego.github.io/blog/2015/10/23/Interpreting-Model-Output-In-R

https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/wordpress/

http://3.14a.ch/archives/2015/03/08/how-to-publish-with-r-markdown-in-wordpress/

RWordPress does not seem to support graphical outputs from the script. Instead of discussing the multitude of errors I received and options I tried, my simple question is: How did the above listed examples manage to put R code and graphs on their websites? (I haven't tried to contact those homepage owners, but this will be the next step, if no explanation can be found.)

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. It depends if you want to build your website from scratch or not. In the first case, I recommend you to have a look at:

- `bookdown`: very nice for documentation. You can find many examples on the web, for instance the [bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/)
- `blogdown`: more general than `bookdown`. This gives very nice websites ([mine](https://linogaliana.netlify.com/) is built using `blogdown` for instance). `blogdown` is based on `hugo`: you can find many themes.

In both cases, you write standard `Rmarkdown` and build your site by executing the markdowns. You can build the site locally for preview or deploy them on the web (manually or by a continuous integration system as gitlab pages). The point of using these packages is reducing the burden of handling formatting and links between pages.

Comment: I would prefer to use a Wordpress format and not to build a website from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is a mixture of manual and automatic generation. If you look at my website (www.jamescurran.co.nz), you'll find articles like the ones you want to write.

I achieve this in a variety of ways. Sometimes I get knitr to produce the HTML, and then I hack it into shape on the website. Other times, I use a mixture of short-tags like

```
[code language = "R"]
data(cars)
[/code]
```

and/or HTML like

```
<pre><code>
data(cars)
</code><pre>
```

The images I upload and then use Wordpress' editor to insert the correct links. It's not very satisfactory, but unless you have a hosting platform that allows you to have static content, then most of the automated solutions that go straight from R Markdown won't work.

Comment: "Sometimes I get knitr to produce the HTML, and then I hack it into shape on the website." I once tried on to put HTML Code from a Markdown document as html-element on my wordpress-site. It squeezed my layout, but already included a graph. It's version which almost provides a solution, but fixing the layout manually requires more HTML knowledge than I have, I guess.

Comment: The main issue I have is that it adds (for some reason I can't figure) a big chunk of white space below the title :-)